# ASM Java BCI , tracing method argument values/method return values

Tags: java, assembly

I am using ASM to inject some simple tracing instructions into methods in my Java program, method entered, method exited, timestamps etc...

This all works great.

I now want to augment this and inject instructions to capture method argument values and method return values , using ASM in a fashion that can be generically applied to any method.

Any code examples to point me in the right direction much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ASM argument example
refer to (https://github.com/scouter-project/scouter/blob/master/scouter.agent.java/src/scouter/agent/asm/CapArgsASM.java)

```
Type.getArgumentType(desc) // get arguments types. return Type[]
mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ILOAD, index) // load parameter to stack
```

ASM return example
refer to (https://github.com/scouter-project/scouter/blob/master/scouter.agent.java/src/scouter/agent/asm/CapReturnASM.java)

```
public void visitInsn(int opcode) {
    if ((opcode >= IRETURN && opcode <= RETURN)) {
        //return value is on the top stack
    }
    mv.visitInsn(opcode);
}
```